# function called multiple times causes program to exit with enigmatic error

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I isolated the problem to this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

const wchar_t* readLine(int posX, int posY, int len) {
  wchar_t* wcharFromConsole = new wchar_t[len];
  COORD pos = {posX,posY};
  DWORD dwChars;
  ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
    wcharFromConsole,  // Buffer where store symbols
    len,     // Read len chars
    pos,    // Read from row=8, column=6
    &dwChars);  // How many symbols stored
  wcharFromConsole [dwChars] = L'\0'; // Terminate, so string functions can be used
  return wcharFromConsole;
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 63; i++) {
    readLine(0,0,80);
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

The thing is if the loop is running less than 63 times it works, if length of chars loaded from console is less than 80 it also works... I have no Idea what is happening here. Are there any resources I must explicitly close... but why, if a function closes it should close also all of its resources. But what is happening here I have no idea, the compiled program (without any error) exits before silently `system()` function. There were other error codes as I removed portions of code from my project, sometimes it was that program requested termination in a unusual way, at other times program hanged and stopped accept keyboard input.

--
edit:

I've updated the code according to suggestions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

const wchar_t* readLine(int posX, int posY, int len) {
  wchar_t* wcharFromConsole = new wchar_t[len];
  COORD pos = {posX,posY};
  DWORD dwChars = 0;
  if(!ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
    wcharFromConsole,  // Buffer where store symbols
    len,     // Read len chars
    pos,    // Read from row=8, column=6
    &dwChars))  // How many symbols stored
  {
    cout << "ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW failed, code" << GetLastError() << endl;
  }
  wcharFromConsole [dwChars] = L'\0'; // Terminate, so string functions can be used
  return wcharFromConsole;
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    cout << "loop count: " << i << endl;
    readLine(0,0,80);
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

output:

```
loop count: 0
loop count: 1
loop count: 2
loop count: 3
// [...]
loop count: 63
loop count: 64

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

(The first snipped didn't produce any error at all.)

Comment: One thing you're not doing is `delete[]`ing `wcharFromConsole`.

Comment: Have you considered checking the return code of ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW and GetLastError ?

Comment: @chris: how to delete a variable in a function since I have to return it, and the return is the last command executed in a function ?

Comment: @rsk82, You'd have to store it to a `const wchar_t *` in `main` and `delete[]` that. Probably better is returning a `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: A function doesn't "close". There is no such concept. Your assumption that anything should happen magically is just not how C++ works. It's *near* magic, but only in ways that can be described explicitly.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: `GetLastError()` is always 0.

Comment: compiler: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

Comment: It won't be when the function fails. I bet dwChars is left unintialized when the function fails and `wcharFromConsole [dwChars] = L'\0'1` is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just the "off by one". You are allocating space for "Len" characters, you reading "Len" characters, but you're putting an additional \0 at the end.

Change your new to allocate Len+1 and you'll probably be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`dwChars` should be passed to `ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW` as `dwChars -1`.
You're overwriting the end of the array.